# Probability of extinction in branching process

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a branching process where the offspring distribution is given by $$P(X = k) = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$

what is the probability that the process becomes extinct at exactly at the $n$th generation?

The answer is supposed to be $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Wouldn't it be the generating function $\phi_n(0) - \phi_{n-1}(0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generating function is
$$
\phi(t)=\sum_{k\ge 0} {\mathbb{P}}(X=k) t^k=\frac{1}{2-t}
$$
and it's easy to prove by induction that the $n$-fold composition of $\phi(t)$ with itself is
$$
\phi^{(n)}(t)=\frac{n-(n-1)t}{(n+1)-nt}
$$
so the probability that the process is extinct by the $n$th generation is
$$
\phi^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n}{n+1}$$
and as you say the probability that it becomes extinct exactly at generation $n$ is
$$
\phi^{(n)}(0)-\phi^{(n-1)}(0)=\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}.
$$

Comment: What would be the mean total size?

Comment: @teddy1203109238 There is a general theorem about this in your notes.